# Why is my logic not adding the quotes back to the CSV File for the columns after the First one?

Tags: c#, loops, csv, for-loop

I am using hashmaps to store `CSVFile1` and compare it to `CSVFile2`. `CSVFile1` has a column of customers to remove while `CSVFile2` has all of the completed data (which has more then 1 column and that is why I am only comparing dataArray2[0]). Once I compare I only rewrite the files that are **NOT** in the `CSVFile1` to a file called **`CSVFileFinal`**.

The issue is that some of the data has commas inside of fields and when I read the file it take them out once I try and rewrite. My goal is to rewrite the data with the quotes back around the commas in the fields which I "split" at.

I have managed to get the First column (the most important one) to split and replace the quotes perfectly! But for whatever reason my second loop is messing up and not checking the columns after that correctly. I believe it is simply the placing of my code.

This is the logical statement/placement in question:

```
if (dataArray2[i].Contains(","))
{
    string x = "\"" + dataArray2[i] + "\"";
    record = x;
}
```

I know the logic works because if you look at my entire source code; the code posted works for the first column and works in the 2nd IF statement for `If i == 0` meaning if it's the 1st columns. But how or where do I place that to work for the others afterward?

***Can anyone help figure out where to place this for the following columns?
It should be a simple copy and pasting of the code I have but I've been unable to figure it out. Thank you!***

```
    int count = 0;
    while (!CSVFile2.EndOfData)
    {
        if (!badCustomers.ContainsKey(dataArray2[0]))
        {
            String record = null;
            for(int i = 0; i < dataArray2.Length; i++)
            {
                if(i == 0)
                {
                    if (dataArray2[i].Contains(","))
                    {
                        string x = "\"" + dataArray2[i] + "\"";
                        record = x;
                    }
                    else
                        record = dataArray2[i];
                } else
                {
                    record = record + "," + dataArray2[i];

                }
            }
            count++;
            if( count % 50 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(count);
            }
            output.WriteLine(record);
        }
        dataArray2 = CSVFile2.ReadFields();
    }
```

The above code works but does not consider the later columns after the first one to replace this quotes- this code is what should fix the ones after the first column but for whatever reason it does not. Why?

```
 if (!badCustomers.ContainsKey(dataArray2[0]))
                {
                    String record = null;
                    for(int i = 0; i < dataArray2.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if(i == 0)
                        {
                            if (dataArray2[i].Contains(","))
                            {
                                string x = "\"" + dataArray2[i] + "\"";
                                record = x;
                            }
                            else
                                record = dataArray2[i];
                        } else
                        {
                            if (dataArray2[i].Contains(","))
                            {
                                string x = "\"" + dataArray2[i] + "\"";
                                record = x;
                            }
                            else
                                record = record + "," + dataArray2[i];

                        }
                    }
```

Comment: The way I would have approached this problem is build a class to store the data you want, load data from CSVFile2 and create a list of these objects to represent the original data set.  Then I would remove items from this list that appear on CSVFile1.  Finally, I would create the new file from the remaining data in the list.

Comment: Why are you trying to make your own CSV parser / writer?  There are quite a few libraries out there that already do this.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus I like that approach. I would however like to keep what I have at the moment. Can you see where I should copy and paste the logic I have in my code? What I have works fine for the first column just not for the ones afterward :/

Comment: @Becuzz You are correct! I am trying to simply practice and make my own for a data conversion project at work.

Comment: I am unsure as to why I'd receive a downvote on a question that is simply asking a question concerning my logic. I wish people would teach/direct instead of being so negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I believe you are asking is for this:

```
int count = 0;
while (!CSVFile2.EndOfData)
{
    if (!badCustomers.ContainsKey(dataArray2[0]))
    {
        String record = String.Empty;
        for(int i = 0; i < dataArray2.Length; i++)
        {
            if (dataArray2[i].Contains(","))
            {
                 string x = "\"" + dataArray2[i] + "\"";
                 record += x;
            }
            else
            {
                 record += dataArray2[i];
            } 
            if (i < dataArray.Length -1)
            {
                  record += ",";
            }
        }
        count++;
        if( count % 50 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(count);
        }
        output.WriteLine(record);
    }
    dataArray2 = CSVFile2.ReadFields();
}
```

This loops through each line from the input, adding quotes around commas.  You may have to tweak it to meet your final needs, but this should be a start.

The reason it was only ever doing it for your first column is the if(i == 0).  This means the code would only ever execute for the first iteration (your first column).

Comment: Thank you for answering and being constructive! I figured what I had would work if I just placed the statement I made after the other else too but it didnt. Because if `i` is not equal to 0 then it's not equal to the first column so it should check those right?

Comment: i == 0 represents the first column.  Any other value of i would be a later column (if I'm understanding your dataArray structure correctly

Comment: That is correct! But for what ever reason when I paste `if (dataArray2[i].Contains(","))
{
    string x = "\"" + dataArray2[i] + "\"";
    record = x;
}`      a second time for the ELSE part (meaining ELSE if it is not the first column) do the exact same thing and replace the quotes back in.

Comment: I will edit my OP to show what I am doing to try and fix it but I dont understand why it isn't fixing the later columns like you said. Ill post it now. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: record = x will overwrite record with the value of x.  You are wanting to append it instead, and use record += x.  You should look at the StringBuilder class as it is more efficient for making concatenated strings

Comment: Oh so you saying I need to use record = record + x instead of simply record = x ? Also I have updated my orginal post with the code I think should work but does not. Could you explain why? Thank you

Comment: record = x replaces record with x (which is your current column with quotes if it has a comma).  record += x or record = record + x appends x to the end of the column.

Comment: Thank you Marshall for taking the time to explain and to help me. After trying and tinkering- your answer was correct! Thank you :)